# print json fields and data on ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json

I'm working on ruby and i have the following line:

```
error = new_user.errors.to_json
```

if I do 
`puts error` 
the following json would be printed: 
`{"email":["is invalid"]}`
and I want is to show the following text "the email entered is invalid"
so how can I access both key and value from json?

thanks

Comment: Are you using Ruby on Rails?

Comment: yes, sorry for not mentioning it before

Comment: It seems to be ActiveRecord Validation errors attribute. At model level validation, you can use 'message' option and set your custom error message. 

validates_format_of :email, :with => /\A([^@\s]+)@((?:[-a-z0-9]+\.)+[a-z]{2,})\Z/i, :message => "The email entered is invalid"

Comment: could you enter a code example for me to understand it better?

Comment: if you want to print error message in view, then take a look at this link http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#displaying-validation-errors-in-views

Comment: follow this http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Validations/ClassMethods/validates_format_of

Comment: what i truly want is to get access to the key part (email) and the value part (is invlaid) so i can be able to print it. because messages can change depending on the type of error.

Comment: error["email"] = "your custom message"

Comment: does it suites your need, new_user.errors.full_messages.each do |error|
puts error
end

Comment: what if i dont know the key field? i mean, if im not able to do error["email"] because i dont know which field is going to be the one with the error. there's a way to get the key if i know there is going to be one for sure?

Comment: if you want to do thins with ruby then don't convert it to a json. you can get the key like this,  "user.errors.each do |key,value| puts key end". here key will prints "email" in your case.

Comment: Do you want to do your formatting in ruby, or in javascript?  What is the json for?

Answer (score 1):

if you want to print the error messages, my suggestion is to try like this,

```
new_user.errors.full_messages.each do |error| 
  puts error 
end
```

to know more about ActiveRecord errors take a look the links [ActiveRecord::Errors](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v2.3.8/classes/ActiveRecord/Errors.html), [Working with Validation Errors](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#working-with-validation-errors)